# How can I get list of Extensions/add-ons installed in Firefox and Internet Explorer using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to get the list of all Extensions Installed in the browsers.

For IE I'm able to find only a few extensions in registry at 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions.

For Firefox I located the place of profiles but not able to extract information from those profile.

If I enter "about:support" in address bar I am getting all information but not able to extract those information using c#.

Comment: What are you trying to do? IMHO the most cases are for implementing malware and I do not support this.

Comment: I Just want the List of extensions installed.

Answer (score 1):

When someone asks a a question, and then stackoverflow users ask them "Why"? I feel they are taking it off topic. Just answer the question if you know it. It's up to staff to decide if the topic should be removed due to malcontent. If you feel that strongly about it report it and let them do their job, rather then taking the question off topic.

### IE

I don't know

### Firefox

In the profiles folder there are two files. One is called addons.json and the other is extensions.json they are different somehow, I can't recall. If you find out please share. But they contain the info on all installed addons (enabled/disabled/etc).

Comment: `When someone asks a a question, and then stackoverflow users ask them "Why"? I feel they are taking it off topic.` Thank you for saying that aloud!

Comment: Thanks @rootkea for that. When other users ask the original poster (OP) "why"/"what" it forces the original poster into an XY situation. It's the weirdest thing, the users as the OP "why?" then after he replies they vote to close the topic due to "XY off topic".